# For loop in multi-thread doesn't work correctly

Tags: java, multithreading

I create new Thread and start it. It's run method has following code:

```
for (int a=0; a<10; a++) {
    System.out.println(a);
    Thread.sleep(10);
}
```

And what I get is:

`0
0
1
1
2
0
2
3
1
0
3
4
2
1
0
4
5
3
2
1
0
5
6
4`

... and so on. Why I don't get `1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9` ? What's the reason?

**EDIT:**

Thread code:

```
private class WarpEnemyRnn implements Runnable {
    private WarpEnemy enemy;

    public WarpEnemyRnn(WarpEnemy enemy) {
        this.enemy = enemy;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            for (int a=0; a<8; a++) {
                System.out.println(a);
                enemy.subOpacity();
                Thread.sleep(refreshRate);
            }
            Point2D warpPoint = enemy.warp();
            enemy.setX((int) warpPoint.getX());
            enemy.setY((int) warpPoint.getY());
            enemy.resetWarpCooldown();
            for (int a=0; a<8; a++) {
                enemy.addOpacity();
                Thread.sleep(refreshRate);
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

New thread is created in other thread which runs every 15ms. It's created only when some condition agrees.

Comment: Without showing the multithreaded part of your code, there is no way you will receive a specific answer. But it seems you are starting several threads which have interleaved executions.

Comment: Can you show some more code? Specially the place where you are creating your threads, and the place where this for loop is?

Comment: Be happy - you're program is successfully multithreaded!

Comment: The output suggests that you have at least 6 of these guys. Show us where you create them.

Comment: @user2080377 If you have several threads running in parallel, what do you find unexpected in the output?

Comment: well.. does the other thread also print out something?

Comment: We don't know what is happening in your `subOpacity` and `addOpacity` method, but your code seems to be ok. And the output you get is as expected when runnning 5-6 threads in interleaved manner. Why would you get surprised by that output?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

All threads print to the same standard output.

Every time you see a 0 printed out is when a new thread is created.

Here are your threads:

```
0   1   2     3       4         5           6  
  0   1     2       3         4           5    
          0     1       2         3           4
                  0       1         2
                            0         1
                                        0
```

Each is printing the numbers in sequence.

Note - It's not guaranteed for each output to be assigned to the thread I specified, this is just one possible alignment of outputs (e.g. the output of the the first two threads are interchangeable), but the timing suggests that this is indeed the correct assignment.

You could add a unique ID to each thread if you want to see which thread prints what.

Answer (score 0):

> New thread is created in other thread which runs every 15ms. It's created only when some condition agrees.

You haven't shown that code, but I expect what's happening is that you're creating and running multiple `WarpEnemyRnn` instances. Your condition that starts one up probably needs a guard for whether it's *already* fired one up.

Answer (score 0):

The same resource: `System.out` is shared by all your threads.

If you want to see correct outputs, you have to synchronize it, **but it's not a good practice because it reduce the concurrency**.

```
private class WarpEnemyRnn implements Runnable {
    private WarpEnemy enemy;

    public WarpEnemyRnn(WarpEnemy enemy) {
        this.enemy = enemy;
    }

    @Override public void run() {
        try {
           synchronize( System.out) {           //<<<<<<< HERE IS THE SYNCHRO
              for (int a=0; a<8; a++) {
                 System.out.println(a);
              }
           }
           for (int a=0; a<8; a++) {
              enemy.subOpacity();
              Thread.sleep(8*refreshRate);
           }
           ...
```

Comment: Synchronizing on System.out is a really bad idea.

Comment: @Aubin If you know, why do it and not use something else?

Comment: @Aubin - not worded strongly enough imo, but you did mention it.

Comment: English is not my primary language, sorry...